# Jquery Tabs - Flash of Unstyled Contnet (FOUC)

Tags: jquery

I am getting the Flash of Unstyled Content as this loads and can't get any of the solutions to work:

```
<html>

 <head>

  <title>demo</title>

  <link type="text/css" href="css/cupertino/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/ui.core.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/ui.tabs.js'></script>

 </head>

 <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
 </script>

<div class="demo" class="ui-tabs">

<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs-hide">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
  <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
  <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-3">
  <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
  <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
 </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description">

<p>Click tabs to swap between content that is broken into logical sections.</p>

</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the *ui-tabs* class to the *tabs* div and the *ui-tabs-hide* to each *tabs-** div.

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-hide">
      <p>Tab Content</p>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-hide">
      <p>Morbi tincidunt</p>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-hide">
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. </p>
      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula</p>
     </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: This solution does not seem to work 100% in IE7 and below.  The tab itself still loads unstyled, but at least the tab content does not appear until styled.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem,ui-tabs-hide will hide the tabs not the href,to hide it you have just need to use a simple trick of hiding it till body loads completely

```
<ul id="customtabs" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1a>li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2a>li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3a>li>
ul>
```

Then unhide it under document.ready jquery

```
$('#customtabs').css('visibility','visible');
```

See the full working example [here](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/06/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_22.html)